# JavaScript remove item from nested Array

Tags: javascript

My code looks like this. At the beginning I have defined nested arrays

```
var license= [{ 
    packet: [{
        pay: [],
        channel: [],
        fun: []
    }] 
}];
```

Add item work corect

```
function addPayChannelToObject(name) {

    var paychannel = { name: name };
    license[0].packet[0].pay.push(paychannel);

    console.log(pay);
}
```

How can I delete an item by value?

```
function removeItemFromObject(name) {

    //??
    console.log(pay);
}
```

Comment: You seem to know how to access the *nested* array, and the remaining question "delete an item by value" is a plain duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
 function removeItemFromObject(name) {

     var index = license[0].packet[0].pay.indexOf(name); // found index of value
     if(index > -1){
       license[0].packet[0].pay.splice(index, 1); //remove index
     }
     console.log(pay);
   }
```

Comment: if indexOf results in `-1` it will remove the last item, though none were found