# Removing a item from object with nested arrays

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, multidimensional-array

Hi I have object like this

```
var obj= {
     _id: string;
    name: string;
    loc: [{
         locname: string;
         locId: string;
         locadd: [{
             st: string;
             zip: string;
         }]
     }]
}
```

Using typescript in angular 2 I want to delete a particular row

```
deleterow(i, j) {
  // i is index of loc 
  // j is index of locadd
  this.obj.loc.splice(i, 1) //works fine 
  this.obj.loc[i].locadd.splice(j, 1) //doesn't work. I don't get any error just 
  // row is not removed.
}
```

I am trying solution similar to given in this answer but doesn't work

[JavaScript remove item from nested Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24430710/javascript-remove-item-from-nested-array)

Please let me know how I can remove the an item from locadd
Thanks

Comment: What is `j`? `"locadd"` property has a single value `.splice(0, 1)`. Given the value of `"locadd"` at the object at the question any value greater than `0` passed to first parameter of `.slice()` will not match any index within the array.

Comment: locadd is an array. j is index for locadd that I want to be removed.

Comment: Does `"locadd"` contain more than one element?

Comment: yes it is more than one element

Comment: Can you include the complete object and the expected result at the question and create a stacksnippets to demonstrate the issue? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: loc is array too...Yes at i it is only one property  this.obj.loc[i]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You deleted `i`th loc item. And then, You've referenced `i`th loc which is **next of deleted loc item**.

I think `locadd` should be deleted before delete `loc`.

```js
this.obj.loc[i].locadd.splice(j,1)
this.obj.loc.splice(i, 1)
```

**Update**

I've made a snippet. It seems working.

```js
var obj = {
  loc: [{
    locadd: [{
      st: '1',
      zip: '1',
    },{
      st: '2',
      zip: '2',
    },{
      st: '3',
      zip: '3',
    }]
  }]
};

function deleterow(i, j) {
  // i is index of loc 
  // j is index of locadd
  // this.obj.loc.splice(i, 1) //works fine 
  this.obj.loc[i].locadd.splice(j, 1) //doesn't work. I don't get any error just 
  // row is not removed.
}

console.log(this.obj.loc)
deleterow(0, 1)
console.log(this.obj.loc)
```

Comment: it doesn't work cause I am just trying this  this.obj.loc[i].locadd.splice(j,1)  The other this.obj.loc.splice(i,1) is just to show on first aray it works fine but nested it is not working

Comment: I was trying to edit your code snipped didn't know how to. Can you add a second element on locadd[0] than remove the one. Cause I believe that is where it doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: @J.Davidson Can you update your post what your intended by code?

Comment: Thank you for the snippet. Using it I was able to find out issue with j value, once corrected it worked fine. Thanks